# AVAsset from app sandbox

Tags: ios, audio, sandbox, avasset, avurlasset

I'm working with AVAsset in my app and met next problem. 
When I'm writing something like this:

```
AVAsset *audioAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Hello.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]]];
```

its work fine. But when I trying get fresh recorded file from my tmp directory from in app's sandbox like that:

```
AVAsset *audioAsset2 = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"speechRecord" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"m4a"]]]];
```

it doesn't work too. Even if I trying add video file to asset from sandbox - result is the same.
I even tried work with `AVURLAsset`, but asset always empty too. I need it to mix two audio files between themselves and then merge it with recorded video. If I can do that without AVAssets and there is another way, I will appreciate if You tell me. Or may there is some another function for that?

Answer (score 3):

You create the second URL for audioAsset2 with the `URLWithString` selector. Your first asset loaded correctly, because you used the `fileURLWithPath` selector.

If you want to load a file at a given URL always create the NSURL object with the `fileURLWithPath` selector.

So simply try:

```
AVAsset *audioAsset2 = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"speechRecord" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"m4a"]]]];
```